# Why is the 'contains' not working? or I am doing it wrong?

Tags: java

Objectives:

1. Check if the user input is a letter
2. Check if it is a vowel or consonants
3. Check if there's a duplicate letter in a String

Contains not returning anything or I am using it wrong

```
Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please insert a text: ");

    String[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}; 
    String userInput = out.nextLine();
    char[] charUserInput = userInput.toCharArray();
    String temp = "";
    String temp1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= charUserInput.length -1; i++){
        if (Character.isLetter(charUserInput[i])){
            if (Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(vowels[0]) || (Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(vowels[1]) ||
                    (Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(vowels[2]) || (Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(vowels[3]) || 
                            (Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(vowels[4])))))){
                    if (!Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).contains(temp)){
                        temp += Character.toString(charUserInput[i]);
                    }
            }else{
                if (!Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).contains(temp1)){
                    temp1 += Character.toString(charUserInput[i]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(temp1);
    out.close();
```

Comment: What error you getting ?

Comment: It returns only a blank one. Nothing else..

Comment: temp1 is only ever initialised as "".

Comment: Is it wrong to initialized it? I am accumulating the letters, why is it not working though?

Comment: Btw on a side note, you should stick with either `char` or `String` troughout your code. I`m sure you can work a way to cast elements once at the beginning and stick with the same data type. Too much casting makes a mess of a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you inverted conditions: use

```
temp.contains(Character.toString(charUserInput[i]))
```

instead of

```
Character.toString(charUserInput[i]).contains(temp)
```

Comment: Ohh it is working now! How is it wrong the other way around? Can you explain please? Thank you

Comment: @user3323654 as [String docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) state, "Returns true if and only if **this** string contains the **specified sequence** of char values". That means that the method checks whether the argument is contained in the string, not the opposite.